# Using if statement on private method inside of show or controller page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a submissions_controller that has two private methods below

```
private

def set_submission
 @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
end

def related_submissions
 @related_submissions = Submission.where(category_id: @submission.category_id)
end
```

Inside of my show.html.erb file i'm using this private method of related_submissions. If there are any related submissions with the same id, i'm showing them.

I have that `next if` in there to not show the current submission. The other conditional inside is checking if my image parameter is there.

```
<div id="submissions" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-9">
 <% @related_submissions.each do |submission| %>
  <% next if submission == @submission %>
   <div>
    <% if submission.image.attached? %>
     <%= link_to submission do %>
      <%= image_tag submission.image, alt: submission.title %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="submission-info">
     <%= link_to submission.title, submission %>
     <div>
      <%= link_to submission.url, target: :_blank do %>
       <div>
        <%= render_svg "icons/arrow-link" %>
       </div>
      <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

This is all working fine how I want, but I want to change the logic if there are no related submissions to show.

How can I check using this private method of related_submissions to do the below?

**if there are any related submissions coming through with same category id**

**show related submissions with same category id**

**else**

**show this text "There are no related submissions."**

**end**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modification of before action allows you to skip `next` in the view

`load` avoids double sql request in the view

```
def related_submissions
  @related_submissions = Submission.where(category_id: @submission.category_id).where.not(id: params[:id]).load
end
```

This is view modification

```
<% if @related_submissions.any? %>
  <% @related_submissions.each do |submission| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no related submissions.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should be using `includes(:image)` instead of `load` which doesn't actually do anything to prevent the N+1 query issue that will occur in the view. Otherwise its a good answer.

Comment: **Anton Bogdanov**, thanks so much for contributing to this. I'll definitely be implementing this soon and see how it goes! Will keep you updated.

**max**, i'll take note of that!

Comment: I keep getting these errors. I'll continue to look into it.

app/views/submissions/show.html.erb:133: else without rescue is useless 

app/views/submissions/show.html.erb:157: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input

Comment: I needed another <% end %> before the <% else %> for the do block in the initial if statement.

Comment: @Suedehead looks like in my answer I used condition like

`if ... do`

and this is wrong, I changed answer

Comment: @AntonBogdanov Got it, I thought it looked slightly off. This is working and thank you again!